# Gigya Gamification SDK Tutorial for iOS Application

Tags: ios, gigya

I want to include Gamification feature in my iOS app.  want to achieve it through Gigya SDK.How is it possible? Is any good tutorial available for it?

Comment: Hi, i am also working on the same feature, will you plz guide me on this,plz save me.

Answer (score 0):

The client-side gamification plugins (achievement, challenge status, leaderboards, notifications, user status) are only available for use within a web browser through javascript.

While it should be possible to include a web-view to display any of these plugins from inside your mobile app, most of these plugins do not make sense to use in a mobile context.

If you are interested in pursuing this functionality then you can include a web-view which hosts the web pages that load the gamification plugins, and then sync the web-view session through the use of the [GSWebBridge class](http://wikifiles.gigya.com/SDKs/iPhone/doc/html/Classes/GSWebBridge.html). Gigya has [documentation](http://developers.gigya.com/035_Mobile_SDKs/010_iPhone#Integrating_Your_Site_with_the_iOS_SDK) on how this can be achieved with sample code.

---

If you are looking to award custom actions that are performed from within your app. This can be accomplished by making calls to [gm.notifyAction](http://developers.gigya.com/037_API_reference/040_GM/gm.notifyAction) to the [Gigya API from your iOS code](http://developers.gigya.com/035_Mobile_SDKs/010_iPhone#Initialization).

---

Other than that, if you are looking for a more out-of-the-box solution, then you should contact the support team at Gigya and have them file a Feature Request for you.  Gigya doesn't currently offer an out-of-the-box solution to accomplish this, and there is no tutorial because of that.